# how to parse json string contains circular reference in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following json string in javascript. This string contains a circular references. I want to parse this string in such a way that the reference will be replaced by its actual object. I use `Json.Parse` but it creates the json object with references. Is there any way by whihc i can achieve this ?

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Event": {
        "$id": "3",
        "Invitaions": {
          "$id": "4",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            },
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "Event": {
                "$ref": "3"
              },
              "Id": 2,
              "Name": "test2",
              "Date": "24",
              "EventId": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "marriage",
        "Address": "abcd"
      },
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "test1",
      "Date": "23",
      "EventId": 1
    },
    {
      "$ref": "5"
    },
    {
      "$id": "6",
      "Event": {
        "$id": "7",
        "Invitaions": {
          "$id": "8",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "6"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "birthday",
        "Address": "abcd"
      },
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "test3",
      "Date": "25",
      "EventId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nothing pre-baked in JavaScript itself or jQuery. You'll have to write it (or find a plug-in/script that someone has already written to do it). Quite straight-forward to take the object graph returned by `parse` and loop through finding `$ref` properties and replacing them.

Comment: have you tried this plugin: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ ?

Comment: What has built this JSON with circular references, does that tool not provide a JavaScript parse function?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
function resolveReferences(json) {
    if (typeof json === 'string')
        json = JSON.parse(json);

    var byid = {}, // all objects by id
        refs = []; // references to objects that could not be resolved
    json = (function recurse(obj, prop, parent) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' || !obj) // a primitive value
            return obj;
        if ("$ref" in obj) { // a reference
            var ref = obj.$ref;
            if (ref in byid)
                return byid[ref];
            // else we have to make it lazy:
            refs.push([parent, prop, ref]);
            return;
        } else if ("$id" in obj) {
            var id = obj.$id;
            delete obj.$id;
            if ("$values" in obj) // an array
                obj = obj.$values.map(recurse);
            else // a plain object
                for (var prop in obj)
                    obj[prop] = recurse(obj[prop], prop, obj)
            byid[id] = obj;
        }
        return obj;
    })(json); // run it!

    for (var i=0; i<refs.length; i++) { // resolve previously unknown references
        var ref = refs[i];
        ref[0][ref[1]] = byid[refs[2]];
        // Notice that this throws if you put in a reference at top-level
    }
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Douglas Crockfords JSON-js repo on github: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

There's a cycle.js in there that helps you do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my post here, I've found some bugs in the code above and there wasn't arrays support, check out my improved version: [Resolve circular references from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312529/resolve-circular-references-from-json-object/15757499#15757499)