# RESTful service empty response

Tags: java, android, json, rest, glassfish

I have problem with REST service I'm trying to make. I use GlassFish 4.1 and Jersay 2.1 which is built-in.

```
@Path("/driver")
@RequestScoped
public class DriverResource {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DriverResource.class);

        @Inject
        private DriverManager driverManager;

        private SharedResponseFactory responseFactory = new SharedResponseFactory();

        @GET
        @Path("/login/{pesel}/{password}")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response logIn(@PathParam("pesel") String pesel, @PathParam("password") String password) {
            try {
                Driver driver = driverManager.logIn(pesel, password);

                logger.debug("Zalogowano kierowcę: " + driver.getFullName());
                return responseFactory.getSuccesResponse(driver);
            } catch (ErrorDAOException e) {
                logger.catching(e);
                return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
            } catch (NoDataFoundDAOException e) {
                logger.catching(e);
                return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.catching(e);
                return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to return my Entity I get response like this:

```
{}
```

In my Entities there are many cyclic references and I don't operate on actual implementation but interfaces. I need to make it the way Retrofit in my Android application could deserialize it.

Glassfish's logs are empty, there are no errors related to rest. I have no idea how to make it working.

I tried to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` to handle cyclic references and `@JsonTypeInfo` to make interfaces possible to desserialize.

I think there's a small trick that will make it working but unfortunately I don't know it...

Answer (score 1):

I found a relatively easy way to test for cyclic references. If you use JAXB (which is included with glassfish), you can try marshalling your entity to XML. A JAXBException is thrown if any cyclic references are found.

Here is a method to marshall an object to XML:

```
public static <T> String marshalToXml(T instance) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(instance.getClass());
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(instance, writer);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

and the service can test the object like this:

```
@Path("/driver")
@RequestScoped
public class DriverResource {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DriverResource.class);

    @Inject
    private DriverManager driverManager;

    private SharedResponseFactory responseFactory = new SharedResponseFactory();

    @GET
    @Path("/login/{pesel}/{password}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response logIn(@PathParam("pesel") String pesel, @PathParam("password") String password) {
        try {
            Driver driver = driverManager.logIn(pesel, password);

            marshalToXml(driver); //remember to import static method

            logger.debug("Zalogowano kierowcę: " + driver.getFullName());
            return responseFactory.getSuccesResponse(driver);
        } catch (ErrorDAOException e) {
            logger.catching(e);
            return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
        } catch (NoDataFoundDAOException e) {
            logger.catching(e);
            return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            //view error message to see cyclic reference
            logger.catching(e);
            return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.catching(e);
            return responseFactory.getFailureResponse(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But sometimes I want to keep this cyclic references. Is there a way to use Jackson and `@JsonIdentityInfo`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Serialized JSON is, at its core, a String. The string will become impossibly deep if the circular references are present. The JSON spec has a way of maintaining those references (with the  $ref property), however you may have to parse the structure on the client side yourself. Check out [This link](http://json-spec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html) about the $ref property and read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118667/how-to-parse-json-string-contains-circular-reference-in-javascript) for more on JSON parsing.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could have properties in the JSON structure which act as IDs for other JSON objects. You can then make rest services which are used to lookup those JSON objects by id.

Comment: I found something like this:
[link](http://www.insaneprogramming.be/blog/2013/07/13/circular-dependencies-with-jackson/). Can I use this? When i added adnotation it wasn's working at all. Is there a way to configure it?

Comment: You could do that to automatically handle creating the JSON reference IDs for you , but on the client side (a web browser or android app) you'll have to recreate the structure using those IDs. This means you'll have to send cyclic entities individually. There may be a way for Jackson to do that for you, but I'm not too familiar with it.